# show/ hide component angular more then once

Tags: angular

I want to achieve the following: when user clicks "login" show login component and hide "register" component , when user clicks "register" show register component and hide "login" component.

My code works only once:  when user clicks "login" show login component and hide "register",
when user clicks "register" show register component and hide "login" component.

but if I click **again** on login it still shows register component.

here my code:

```
<button pButton label="register" (click)="registerOn= true">הרשמה</button>
<button pButton label="login" (click)="loginOn= true">כניסה</button>
<app-register *ngIf="registerOn"></app-register>
<app-login *ngIf="loginOn&&!registerOn"></app-login>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single property to avoid having to manage multiple properties:

```html
<button pButton label="register" (click)="activeComponent='register'">הרשמה</button>
<button pButton label="login" (click)="activeComponent='login'">כניסה</button>
<app-register *ngIf="activeComponent === 'register'"></app-register>
<app-login *ngIf="activeComponent === 'login'"></app-login>
```

component.ts

```js
export class MyComponent {
  activeComponent = 'login';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your logic. `registerOn` and `loginOn` variables are not assigned any false value. You can change it like below by using only one varaible

```
<button pButton label="register" (click)="registerOn= true">הרשמה</button>
<button pButton label="login" (click)="registerOn= false">כניסה</button>
<app-register *ngIf="registerOn; else loginBlock"></app-register>
<ng-template #loginBlock><app-login> </app-login></ng-template>
```